# How to create a directory by combining two name?

Tags: shell-script

I am on Redhat.

I am trying create directory by combining three names.

I have a property file, this is what it looks like:

```
build_name = MyBuild
build_no   = 100
appServer_version = jboss6.1`
```

I read this property file and I am trying to create a directory by combining all three names. After creating directory it should look like that.

```
MYBuild-100-jboss6.1
```

Here what I have tried

```
file="./app.properties"

if [ -f "$file" ]
then
  echo "$file found."

  while IFS='=' read -r key value
  do
    key=$(echo $key | tr '.' '_')
    eval "${key}='${value}'"
  done < "$file"

    echo "build_name    = " ${build_name}
    echo "build_no      = " ${build_no}
    echo "Jboss_version     = "${jboss_version}
    echo "Got the value from property file"


 name=${build_name}-
 build=${build_no}-
 Jboss=${jboss_version}

 fileName="${name}${build}${Jboss}"

    mkdir $fileName

else
  echo "$file not found."
fi
```

When I run this , It always create three different directory,
with name `MyBuild` , `100` , `jboss6.1`. Where am doing wrong.

**update 1**

```
file="./app.properties"

ARRAY=()
if [ -f "$file" ]
then
  echo "$file found."

  IFS='='
  while read -r key value
  do
    val=$(echo "$value" | tr -d '[[:space:]]')
    ARRAY+=("$val")
  done < "$file"

  IFS='-'
  newdir="${ARRAY[*]}"
  echo "mkdir $newdir"

    if[ -f "$newdir" ]
    then 
    echo "$newdir allready exist."
    rm -rf $newdir
    mkdir "$newdir"
    else
    mkdir "$newdir"
else
  echo "$file not found."
fi
```

Comment: You have extra spaces that `read` fetches.  After from `tr '.' '_'` do also `tr -s ' ' | tr -d ' '` for the key. And also perform such a `tr` for the value.

Comment: still it does the same thing, can you please help me with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issue there, first are spaces which are left in your variables when you perform the `read` with `IFS='='`.  Second is that you actually do not have `jboss_version` in your app file.  One way to do this would be:

```
file="./app.properties"

if [ -f "$file" ]
then
  echo "$file found."

  while IFS='=' read -r key value
  do
    key=$(echo $key | tr '.' '_' | tr -d ' ' | tr -d '\t')
    val=$(echo $value | tr -d ' ' | tr -d '\t')
    eval "${key}='${val}'"
  done < "$file"

    echo "build_name    = " ${build_name}
    echo "build_no      = " ${build_no}
    echo "Jboss_version     = "${appServer_version}
    echo "Got the value from property file"


 name=${build_name}-
 build=${build_no}-
 Jboss=${appServer_version}

 fileName="${name}${build}${Jboss}"

    echo mkdir [$fileName]

else
  echo "$file not found."
fi
```

Yet, I would do it in a different way.  By forcing `IFS` to be used in the split and in the join as well, this also uses all variables from the `app.properties` file:

```
file="./app.properties"

ARRAY=()
if [ -f "$file" ]
then
  echo "$file found."

  IFS='='
  while read -r key value
  do
    val=$(echo "$value" | tr -d '[[:space:]]')
    ARRAY+=("$val")
  done < "$file"

  IFS='-'
  newdir="${ARRAY[*]}"
  if [ -d "$newdir" ]; then
      echo "rm -rf $newdir"
      rm -rf "$newdir"
  fi
  echo "mkdir $newdir"
  mkdir "$newdir"
else
  echo "$file not found."
fi
```

Comment: hey thanks thats worked, I would like one more help, If the newdir is already there i want to remove it and create a new one. for that I just added this , but its not working, I am really sorry for asking silly things, because I am totally new to this. please see the updated question

Comment: @varun - If the directory is empty you can simply do `rmdir <dir>` but you did not specify whether it is empty therefore I am assuming it is not.  You need `rm -rf` in that case, I made an edit to the code in the answer.  Note that `rm -rf` can be very destructive, I did an `if` in there for some security but be very careful with forward slashes (`/`) in names if you are using `rm -rf`.

Comment: Thanks , It worked.  I will keep in my what you suggested about rm -rf

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your script, without completely rewriting it you have to:

- strip `value` from any spaces
- use appServer_version in your script, like in the input file not JbossVersion

Working:

```
file="./app.properties"

if [ -f "$file" ]
then
  echo "$file found."

  while IFS='=' read -r key value
  do
    key=$(echo $key | tr '.' '_')
    value=$(echo $value | sed 's/ //g')
    eval "${key}='${value}'"
  done < "$file"

  echo "build_name    = " ${build_name}
  echo "build_no      = " ${build_no}
  echo "Jboss_version     = "${appServer_version}
  echo "Got the value from property file"


  name=${build_name}-
  build=${build_no}-
  Jboss=${appServer_version}

  fileName="${name}${build}${Jboss}"
  echo $fileName
  # mkdir $fileName

else
  echo "$file not found."
fi
```

Comment: I was here writing a better way to do it and you beat me by seconds :), A deserved +1

Comment: @grochmal Sorry for that. I normally don't do much with pure bash, but came across this in the review queue. Your second solution is cleaner IMO.

Comment: I actually meant it in a good way, reminds me to keep my guts. As Mark Pilgrim says: the one who makes the specification is not the one who makes the cleaner spec, but the one who delivers the first implementation.

Answer (score 0):

to skip #comments or some rubbish in app.properties 
    #!/bin/bash

```
FILE="./app.properties"

SEP=
FILENAME=
while read -r LINE; do 
     LINE=$(echo ${LINE} | sed -rn -e  '/=/{/#.*/d;s/[^=]+=([^=]+).*/\1/;s/[ ]*//gp}' )
     [[ -n ${LINE} ]] && FILENAME+=${SEP}${LINE} && [[ -z ${SEP} ]] && SEP="-" 
done <"$FILE"

echo $FILENAME
#mkdir $FILENAME
```